# How to use vector<vector<string>> in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, vector

I saw in c++ code the following:

```
vector<vector<string>> arr(n);
```

I was unable to understand how to use it...

Can anyone explain what is it and how to use var `arr`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is definition of 2 dimension-array of strings with size n.

You can use all places in the upper vector as another string vector.

Look at the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string a = "AAAA";
  string b = "BBBB";
  string c = "CCCC";
  int n = 3;
  vector<vector<string>> arr(n);

  arr[0].push_back(a); // I add string 'a' to end of first vector in 'arr' 
  arr[0].push_back(b);
  arr[1].push_back(c);
  for (int i = 0; i < arr[0].size() ; i++) { // print all string in first vector of 'arr'
     cout << arr[0][i] << " ";
  }
}
```

Comment: The size n is of vector or string?

Comment: Array is ultimately a 3D array so why arr[0][0].push_back(a);  is not used

Comment: how to swap two places in it?

Comment: `n` is the size of the upper vector. It is not 3D but 2D (if you consider string as array of char then it is 3D. Did you try `arr[0][0].push_back(a)`? It cannot be done as you using array method on String var (`arr[0][0]`). You can do swaps as `String temp = arr[0][1]; arr[0][1] = arr[1][0]; arr[1][0] = temp;` hope that helps